# Unexpected render partial with locals behaviour

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, partial-views, yield, locals

I have a partial with yeild blocks, which I set using content_for, when I render partial I am also trying to pass in locals. The locals never get picked up in the partial.

```
<%= render :partial => 'shared/block', :locals => { :cssclass => 'medium' } %>
```

When I try to access the partial using

```
<%= :cssclass %>
```

All I get is the bare "cssclass" as a string rather than the variable I have set it to. Can you not use content_for and render partial at the same time?

**Update**
I tried rendering a partial with locals, no yield or content_for and the the values I setup while rendering the partial are getting picked up. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use <%= cssclass %> instead of symbol. locals set a variable, not a symbol, and when you output symbol it is just converted to string.

Comment: I just get an undefined method or variable exception when I do that